# Cant Print the field values if its a number not string in Firestore

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to print it on a list:

```
li.setAttribute('data-id', updatesArgument.id);//'id' here unique id
  Example 1
  name.textContent = updatesArgument.data().count;// Works if String  
  
  Example 2
  let i=1;
  name.textContent = updatesArgument.data().i;//Does not work if Number

  li.appendChild(name);
  
  infoUpdates.appendChild(li);
```

The Image will show you the
1: "Date/ Bug Fix"

Thats what i want to print on a list:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to know how to solve "Example 2". You need to use the [square brackets notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation), as follows:

```
let i = 1;
name.textContent = updatesArgument.data()[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you maintain correct data modelling for firebase. Anyway, The problem is, When you use `numbers` as `object property`, You should access it like an array index.

**Try**

```js
let i=1;
name.textContent = updatesArgument.data()[i];
```

**Dummy Example**

```js
const obj = {
  1: "Hello",
  2: "Bro",
  count: 8
};

console.log(obj[1]);
console.log(obj[2]);
console.log(obj["count"]);
console.log(obj.count);
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct, but I also would like to add that there may be some conversion issue within your project, and if that is the case, you must cast the number as a string, a simple workaround is

```
name.textContent = "" + updatesArgument.data()['count'];
```

or

```
name.textContent = "" + updatesArgument.data()[1];
```